# derived schemes and perfect obstruction theories

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, stacks, algebraic-stacks, derived-algebraic-geometry

In a survey article of Toen's it is claimed that that there is forgetful $\infty$-functor between the $\infty$-category of derived schemes locally of finite presentation over a field $k$ and the $\infty$-category lfp schemes with perfect obstruction theories and that this functor is neither full  nor faithful.

Question: What are the basic examples of the failure of this functor to be essentially surjective? I am aware of Schurg's paper on giving necessary and sufficient conditions for a perfect obstruction theory to be induced by some derived scheme/stack but I didn't see any concrete examples of the failure of essential surjectivity(there is a good chance I didn't read it closely, in which case I apologize).

Comment: Just to be sure: do you mean "quasi-smooth derived schemes..."? (as suggested by the title).

Comment: yes I will edit it if you like